# adding shallow nested associations controller before action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm use a short form of shallow routing:

```
resources :officers, except: :new

resources :members do
  resources :officers, only: :new
end
```

This is a `member has_many officers : officers belong_to member` association. Members can fill many officer roles over the years, the reason for has_many.

I've had problems dealing with this for years and decided to ask a question on the preferred Rails way of handling the creation of an associated has_many record.

On the Members show page I have a link:

```
= link_to 'New Officer', new_member_officer_path(@member)
```

There is no new_officer_path link in the application, but I wanted to trap someone putting in `officers/new` in the url. In the Officers _form partial, I set a hidden field `member_id` to @member.id if its a new record (`id.nil?`)

My first **failed** attempt:

```
def new
  set_member
  @officer = Officer.new(member_id: @member.id)     
end

def set_member
  if params[:member_id]        
    @member = Active.find(params[:member_id])
  else
    redirect_to members_path, alert: "Officers must be created from the Members Show view"   
  end
end
```

This failed, I guess because you can't redirect from a called method from an action.

I then tried:

```
before_action :set_member, only: :new

def new
  @officer = Officer.new(member_id: @member.id)     
end

def set_member
  if params[:member_id]        
    @member = Active.find(params[:member_id])
  else
    redirect_to members_path, alert: "Officers must be created from the Members Show view"   
  end
end
```

This worked in a valid `members/xx/officers/new` url call but **Failed** in an on `officers/new` url. Since there is not a new route, it went to the show action and failed try to find :id new

Removing the `only: :new` condition on resources officers allow that approach to work, but I have an unneeded route.

Moving stuff around in my first attempt:

```
def new
  set_member
  if @member
    @officer = Officer.new(member_id: @member.id)
  else
    redirect_to members_path, alert: "Officers must be created from the Members Show view"   
  end
end

def set_member
  if params[:member_id]        
    @member = Active.find(params[:member_id])
  end
end
```

Works, but for some reason does not feel right. I almost like leaving the new route in and the before_action approach.

Again, just looking for the standard approach. Also, is setting the foreign id in a hidden field the standard approach?

Comment: If you want to catch a specific route in order to help the user, than that route is not "unneeded" :)

Comment: I agree. Catching an error route makes sense. This combined with the answer using present? and build will seems like the Rails way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would write it like this:

```
def new
  @member = Active.find(params[:member_id]) if params[:member_id].present?
  if @member.present?
    @officer = @member.officers.build
  else
    redirect_to members_path, alert: "Officers must be created from the Members Show view"   
  end
end
```

Using `present?` avoids any potential issues with the way Ruby handles nil as false-y. Not a huge concern, but I think it's best practice to return booleans instead of memorizing Ruby's interpretation of objects to boolean.

Using `build` automatically sets the `member_id`. And I didn't feel that `set_member` needed to be it's own method. However, if the logic in that method gets more complicated, I might revert back to using `set_member`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that present? existed, or forgot about it. I also forgot that I had used build before, but somehow reverted to my old ways.